# Is there a better way to use channels to ensure synchronous access to the map?

Tags: go, maps, channel

I'm using Go maps as an in memory cache and channels to ensure synchronous access.

My "session" package defines the cache as: map[string]*SessionData

SessionData is a struct also defined in the package, along with other access functions as seen in the code.

```
GetWebPage(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
var sd *session.SessionData
var sessTkn string

cookie, err := req.Cookie("sesstoken")

if err == nil { // cookie found
    sessTkn = cookie.Value
    // Check for cache entry for this token,
    // using a channel to protect the map and return
    // a pointer to the cached data if it exists
    sdc := make(chan *session.SessionData, 1)
    go session.GetSessionFromCache(sessTkn, sdc)
    sd = <-sdc

    if sd == nil { // sessTkn not in the cache

        // This is test data to simplify example 
        sv := make([]string, 4)
        sv[0] = sessTkn
        iv := make([]int, 3)
        iv[0] = 100
        iv[1] = 1000

        sdc := make(chan *session.SessionData, 1)
        go session.NewSessionData(sv, iv, false, false, sdc)
        session.SC[sessTkn] = <-sdc
    }

// Is this necessary? Is there a better way?
// ---------------------------------------      
    if sd == nil {
        sdc = make(chan *session.SessionData, 1)
        go session.GetSessionFromCache(sessTkn, sdc)
        sd = <-sdc      
    }
// ---------------------------------------      

    fmt.Println(sd) // just to prove that it works in both cases
}   
// The rest of the handler code follows
```

Comment: To ensure synchronous access you can use [Semaphore package in Go](https://github.com/kamilsk/semaphore)

Comment: @Hamza Thanks for the suggestion. In my case a general purpose semaphore sacrifices the ability communicate (send and receive typed data over the channel). As a desirable side effect, the channel blocks access to the map, assuring async access . None of the access functions qualify as "heavy lifting". The code is working, My only concern is the repetition required to check that a new entry was added to the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [mutex](http://godoc.org/sync#Mutex) to protect the map. A mutex is often simpler than using channels & goroutines to protect a resource.

```
var (
  mu sync.Mutex
  cache = make(map[string]*SessionData)
)

func GetSessionFromCache(sessTkn string) *SessionData {
  mu.Lock()
  defer mu.Unlock()
  sd := cache[sessTkn]
  if sd != nil {
      return sd
  }
  sd := &SessionData{
     // initialize new value here
  }
  cache[sessTkn] = sd
  return sd
}
```

Use it like this:

```
sd := session.GetSessionFromCache(sessTkn)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had started out planning to use a mutex for syncing. Then I read that for higher level applications using channels are better, especially when sharing a data value. I clearly misunderstood. Back to plan A.

Answer (score 1):

Using channels for this particular case have no additional benefit.  If you think about it, even with creating new channels, you can still only have one goroutine that can access the map. Since there is no concurrency benefit here, just use `sync.Mutex`.

```
package session

import "sync"

var cache = struct {
  sync.Mutex
  list map[string]*SessionData
}{
  list: make(map[string]*SessionData),
}

func GetSessionFromCache(token string) *SessionData {
  cache.Lock()
  defer cache.Unlock()
  return cache.list[token]
}
```

Then, no need for a new goroutine.  Just call it directly.

```
sd := session.GetSessionFromCache(sessTkn)
```

Comment: Thanks for the added information as to why channels are not the way to go. I need to do some more study to fully understand exactly what channels do and when their use is appropriate.